# Changing core-tooltip default background color

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, material-design, core-elements

I have the following .html code

```dart
<core-tooltip tipAttribute='tipp'
  id='clock-icon-tip'
  style='background-color: blue;'>
  <div tipp
    style='background-color: red; width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
    <p>this is my tool<br> tip</p>

  </div>
  <core-icon id='clock-icon' class='margin-l-b-4px' icon=''></core-icon>
</core-tooltip>
```

It displays as shown below

[image]

How can I make the black background color red.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the inline style to the style tag because I think this is how it should be done.
I removed the `tipAttribute` because it didn't work for me (probably https://github.com/Polymer/core-tooltip/issues/26 which was fixed recently).

```dart
<template>
  <style>
      core-tooltip#clock-icon-tip core-icon {
        background-color: blue;
      }

      /* tooltip content */
      core-tooltip#clock-icon-tip > [tip],
      /* tooltip background */
      core-tooltip#clock-icon-tip::shadow .core-tooltip {
        background-color: red;
        /*width: 100%;
        height: 100%;*/
      } 

      /* tooltip arrow 
         (needs a rule for each tooltip position, this is for bottom only */
      core-tooltip#clock-icon-tip::shadow .core-tooltip.bottom::after {
        border-bottom-color: red;
      }

  </style>

  <core-tooltip 
    id='clock-icon-tip'
    >
    <div tip>
      <p>this is my tool<br> tip</p>

    </div>
    <core-icon id='clock-icon' class='margin-l-b-4px' icon=''></core-icon>
  </core-tooltip>
</template>
```